# Variables in my while loop are not being updated

Tags: python, function, loops, variables, output

I have two functions in a while loop, one that takes in one argument, and one that takes in three arguments. Each of the arguments is designed to be redefined in the loop, and then and re-entered into the function to calculate the next updated variables. After each loop the output is printed, but in my program, each output is the same as the last which leads me to think that my variables are not updating.
[image]

Comment: your code resets all 3 lists each time around the loop. Is that intended ?
PS. - the norm is to post your code as text within the question.

Comment: It was not supposed to reset all 3 lists, how would I get that to not happen?

Comment: when you do `touristlist = []` that resets the list to be empty; I am not sure what you intended to do though.

Comment: I deleted the list definitions in the loop. My program is still not working the way I want it to though, it's meant to calculate the success population of tourists, bears, and berries for 10 years, but each year I get the same value which leads me to believe that the value of bears, tourists, and berries is not getting updated, which is my problem.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your tourist_next() and find_next() functions are actually working as expected ? your final print in that loop simply prints values from those functions, so that suggests those functions aren't doing what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the lines `touristlist = []`, `bearlist = []`, and `berrielist = []` in the `while` loop. These are causing the lists to reset every loop.

Comment: Note that the print in the loop entirely ignores the lists, so while reseting the lists, is non-sensical - it isn't the root of the problem of getting the same data on each iteration.